# How do I properly deny access to a specific file with Apache 2.4?

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I am runninng Apache 2.4 on Windows 10.  To deny access to DLL files in a specific directory, I try

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
#...
    <Files "*.dll">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
#...
</Directory>
```

Without this, and given a nonexistant file, such as `foo.dll` it gives 404.  With the configuration, the same nonexistant `foo.dll` gives 403, so I know the configuration is valid; however, when I try to access `bar.dll` which exists in the given directory, I'm asked to download it.  Why is that?

How do I figure out what might be overwriting my `<Files ...>` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to achieve what I wanted, I revoked all access in the general case, and explicitly allowed individual files, like this.

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    #...
    Require all denied

    <Files "*.exe">
        Options +ExecCGI
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Require all granted
    </Files>

</Directory>
```

That properly prevents loading of .dll files and everything else extraneous in the directory.